# Microsoft Teams - read out channel messages (ReactJS, NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, microsoft-teams

in Microsoft Teams we have a Team called "BD" and this team has a channel named "Global".

Now I have a ReactJS app with a NodeJS backend and I would like to
display all the messages that are written in the Global Channel of the Team "BD"

I only need to show which messages are written in the channel (so readonly would be sufficient).

What is the easiest way to achieve this ? Even an iFrame would be ok, if somehow possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please take a look at [List channel messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) Graph API. First try these APIs in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).
2. To implement this in a code, you need to follow either [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta) or [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta)
3. Before calling this API with application permissions ([access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta)), you must request access. For details, see [Protected APIs in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis).